# Vertical taskbar on windows server 2008 too wide

Tags: windows, taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 taskbar as sidebar, minimum width fixed](https://superuser.com/questions/181731/windows-7-taskbar-as-sidebar-minimum-width-fixed)

Some people like a vertical taskbar. On older Windows systems it was possible to make it as wide as 1 Icon:

[image]

On some newer Windows operating systems, in my case server 2008, the most narrow that I can size it is as wide as 2 icons:

[image]

How can I override this setting to have a narrow taskbar like before?

**EDIT:** I followed a link in the first answer and it seems it is because the icons do have virtually double the width as it appears (but not double heigth, so you can make a horizontal taskbar the way you like it)

Maybe if I change all Icons to old Icons?

Or Maybe some registry setting?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of Windows you are using, but here are some tips for Windows 7:  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/my-vertical-task-bar-wont-stay-the-right-size-that/b50f137d-f993-4c85-9708-f78d344263e4

[image]

Comment: This is Windows server 2008. It should be like Vista? Anyway, I like your link a lot. I have just read the thread and it points to another thread, and both threads do not solve the issue. I will keep the question open for a while, and if not solved in the end I would accept your answer for pointing to the thread.

Comment: I also applied the settings (never combine and small icon) but it does not help