# How to slim windows 8 taskbar when it is placed as a sidebar?

Tags: windows, windows-8, taskbar

I've seen a couple of solutions for windows 7 but none for windows 8.

Does anyone know how to slim the width of the taskbar when it is set as a side bar?

here is the windows 7 example

original:

[image]

after:

[image]

Any help is appreciated on how to implement this on windows 8, thanks!

Comment: What's the windows 7 solution?  Many tweaks carry over from 7 to 8 and may be worth further investigating.  Note - if it's registry tweaks, then check to see if the same entries exist in 8 and keep track of anything you change (current user stuff is usually not enough to ruin the system).

Comment: @nerdwaller the solution i found was a small tweak using a .bat file, it can be found here: http://superuser.com/questions/181731/windows-7-taskbar-as-sidebar-minimum-width-fixed, sadly this didn't work for windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

This is done in Windows 7 by right-clicking on the taksbar, selecting properties, and checking the check box for "use small icons".

Are you not able to do this in Windows 8? I don't have a windows 8 box available to check myself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this does make the icons smaller but fails to make the actual width of the taskbar any smaller.  This is half way to the solution I guess. :)